# Is it pjscrape that is slow, or is it PhantomJS? Alternative scraper?

Tags: javascript, node.js, screen-scraping, phantomjs

I just wrote my first script for pjscrape, but I find that it runs terribly slow. I'm new to both pjscrape and phantomjs, so I don't know which one is the culprit.

I am loading the file from localhost, so the bottleneck is definitely not in the transfer.

My **config.js** script looks like this:

```
pjs.addSuite({
    url: 'http://localhost/file.html'.
    scraper: function() {
        var people = $('table.person');
        var results = [];

        $.each(people, function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            results.push({ 
                firstName: $this.find('.firstName').text(),
                lastName: $this.find('.lastName').text(),
                age: $this.find('.age').text()
            });
        }

        return results;

    }
}
```

Then I just execute PhantomJS using the command line instructions [here](http://nrabinowitz.github.io/pjscrape/#quickstart).

`~> phantomjs pjscrape.js config.js`

I run the same code (just the scraper function() ) in Chrome and it is instant. In phantomjs/pjscrape, it takes a good 30 seconds.

Any clue what is causing the slowness?

Is there a better way to do this DOM screen scraping? Maybe a nodejs solution?

Comment: Please show phantom.js node code. As issue is probably there.

Comment: @MaksimsMihejevs I'm new to phantom.js so I'm not sure what encompases the "node code". I've edited my question to show the full script. There really isn't much to my part, all the work is done by pjscrape.

Comment: Have you measured what takes most of time to execute? As phantom.js uses QT with WebKit, so your node will ask phantom to run separate process that will launch and initialise all complex components in order to make 'browser' work. And then you can load stuff and interact with it. Initialising phantom - is usually a bottleneck, so you might consider of initialising it once and then reusing. Please measure area that is bottleneck, it is probably initialisation of phantom, but not the script you've posted above.

Comment: I know it's off topic but can you please share how you managed to run it in chrome? Isn't managing the libraries nearly impossible?

Comment: @Shy: When I said, "I run the same code (just the scraper function() ) in Chrome and it is instant," I am referring to just the code that inspects the DOM and grabs values. My test in Chrome involved loading static HTML and running my `scraper` function against it. I never run phantom.js or pjscrape inside of Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Node.JS is an option, might I introduce you to [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio)? It's a great library for consuming questionably-formed HTML documents. It gives you a jQuery-like API for working with a DOM-like representation of the page you're scraping. Paired with [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request), it makes for a pretty easy environment for scraping HTML.

Your example would end up looking something like this (error handling left as an exercise for the reader):

```
var cheerio = require("cheerio"),
    request = require("request");

request("http://localhost/file.html", function(err, res, data) {
  var $ = cheerio.load(data);

  var people = $('table.person');
  var results = [];

  $.each(people, function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    results.push({ 
      firstName: $this.find('.firstName').text(),
      lastName: $this.find('.lastName').text(),
      age: $this.find('.age').text()
    });
  }

  do_something_with(results);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If the web page you are using sends fully-formed HTML and does not require client-side javascript to manipulate the DOM into its final form, skip phantomjs and just scrape with an http client library (node core or [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) or [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) or [hyperquest](https://github.com/substack/hyperquest)) and use [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) to extract the data you need from the DOM.

Comment: You're right, I do not need client-side JS, it's just static HTML. I'll investigate this route.